# is it possible to re-render facebook share buttons with counts?

Tags: facebook

The code I use to render share button is:

```
    <a name="fb_share" share_url="http://www.XYZ.com" type="button_count"></a> 
    <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
            type="text/javascript">
    </script>
```

The above code exists in the page and works fine and when users clicks a button, that action will add the above code (with a different url) to the dom and My goal is to render another facebook button with count. However the problem is that the FB.Share js seems to somehow know it has already did the job and will not render again. 
After poking around with the FB.Share script a bit I found this methoe FB.Share.renderAll() can force a re-render but without count numbers.

Anyone has any insights? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try calling the JavaScript SDK's FB.XFBML.parse(); 
See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: yes, it's working very well on my react and react-router apps. i implemented it on my webpage http://next.kompetisiindonesia.dev/kompetisi/detail/TlRRMQ/Psymotion-2016-Short-Movie-Competition

Answer (score 0):

When you re-add facebook share script, it renders again the share button.

for example: $.getScript("http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share");